# SMTP Authentication with PHP mail() function

Tags: php, email

I'm stuck on trying to add SMTP Authentication to my php script using the PHP mail() function.

The script currently works but because it isn't using SMTP Authentication the path of the php file and many other sensitive details are being included in the header (account username, etc.).

I'm currently specifying some of the header information using "$headers =  ", etc., but I understand I need to use SMTP Authentication to fix this.

Is there a simple way to make my script use SMTP Authentication without having to use phpmailer, etc? Can I simply specify the port, authentication, username, password?

Update: Here is come code:

```
            `code`$eol = PHP_EOL;
            $headers =  "From: Test <test@test.com>".$eol;
            $headers .= "Reply-To: test@test.com".$eol;
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
            $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$random_hash\"".$eol.$eol;
            $subject = 'Subject Goes Here';
            $message="--".$random_hash.$eol;
            $message.="Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8".$eol;
            $message.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
            $message.="Hello,".$eol;
            $message.="Body content goes here.".$eol.$eol;
            $message.="Thank you,".$eol.$eol;
            $message.="--".$random_hash.$eol;
            @mail(to, subject, message, headers);`code`
```

Comment: Which platform? Which MTA? By itself the `mail()` function doesn't do any authorization.

Comment: hi Mario, CENTOS 6.7 with EXIM.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why don't you try the Pear Mail interface something like this:

```
require_once "Mail.php";
$username = 'user@gmail.com';
$password = 'password';
$smtpHost = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$smtpPort = '465';
$to = 'mail@to.com';
$from =  'user@gmail.com';

$subject = 'Contact Form';
$successMessage = 'Message successfully sent!';


$replyTo = '';
$name = '';
$body = '';


$headers = array(
    'From' => $name . " <" . $from . ">",
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
            'host' => $smtpHost,
            'port' => $smtpPort,
            'auth' => true,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password
        ));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo($mail->getMessage());
} else {
    echo($successMessage);
}
```

More information at https://goo.gl/HjffYA

EDIT:

The only way to this without more coding or using external library, is to update sendmail:

Define SMTP Server

```
smtp_server=mail.mydomain.com
```

If you need to change the smtp and SSL ports 
    ; smtp port (normally 25)

```
smtp_port=25

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=auto
```

And finally your authentication credentials for SMTP server:

```
auth_username=username
auth_password=password
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mail.php

Comment: Hello Enzo, thanks for your help. Is it possible to use SMTP Authentication with  the mail() function without relying on PEAR so that I don't have to rewrite all of the php code?

Comment: Hi Enzo, thanks for your help. This might be a silly question, but do I add this to the php file or do I need to edit php.ini and sendmail.ini?

Comment: you did not provide more explanations about changing these configurations.

Comment: Whats in Mail.php???